# Coping files from subfolders where part of path is variable VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro to copy files from folder "Nord" and all subfolders there. Now I need to copy files from only one subfolder in folder Nord called "2020". So path to copy files would be "U:\user\Documents\Nord*\2020" where * is variable and represents name of person, whose data I need to copy. but in each person folder there is few subfloders and I need data from only 2020.

It should copy only files which are not copied yet, thats why I reference to files_list in Masterwb.

Can you help me to modify this code? Should I add there if clause somwhere?
Thank you

```
Sub loopAllSubFolderSelectStartDirectory()

Dim FSOLibrary As FileSystemObject
Dim FSOFolder As Object
Dim folderName As String
Dim Filename As String


'Set the folder name to a variable
folderName = "U:\user\Documents\Nord"

'Set the reference to the FSO Library
Set FSOLibrary = New FileSystemObject

LoopAllSubFolders FSOLibrary.GetFolder(folderName)

End Sub

Sub LoopAllSubFolders(FSOFolder As Object)

Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
Dim fsoFile As Object
Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
Dim NewSht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim Filename As String


targetpath = "C:\Users\Destination\nord\"
Set Masterwb = Workbooks("Raw_data_2020.xlsm")
Set NewSht = Masterwb.Worksheets("files_list")
LastRow = NewSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each FSOFolder In FSOFolder.subfolders

    For Each fsoFile In FSOFolder.Files

        Filename = Dir(fsoFile)
            If Right(fsoFile, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                found = False
                For i = 1 To LastRow
                    If Filename = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                        found = True
                           
                    End If
                Next i
                If Not found Then fsoFile.Copy targetpath

                Filename = Dir
            End If
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: So, the code you posted copy the files if their name are not found in the range 1 to `lastRow` in A:A column of the active workbook. Is this understanding correct? If yes, you now need copying from one folder (it doesn't matter if it is a subfolder of some folder) to another one (no matter if it is a parent folder), but only the file which has not already been copied. Is this understanding correct, too?

Comment: Yes right now it is coping all files from folder and subfolders if name is different than in range 1 to lastRow in A:A. But I want to copy fies only from specific subfloder called "2020". So in folder Nord, there are subfloders with Person names (Alan, Erik etc) and inside of those are folders with years (2020, 2021 etc). I want to enter each person folder and copy only 2020 data which havent been copied before.

Comment: So, your question is not so clear... Inside of "Nord" folder there are some other subfolders (person names) and **inside of these ones there are other subfolders, one of them named as "2020"**. Do you want copying the files from **a specific such 'person/2020'**, or **from all '2020' folders of all existing person subfolders**?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear, I wan to copy from all 2020 folders of all existing person.

Comment: Please, copy the code I pasted. It only checks if the files exist. Should it also check in those sheet A:A range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub copyFromAllSubFoldSpecificNameCheck()
 Dim FSOLibrary As New FileSystemObject, FSONord As Scripting.Folder
 Dim FSOSubfld1 As Scripting.Folder, FSOSubfld2 As Scripting.Folder

 Dim foldNord As String, fldSearch As String, fsoFile As Scripting.File
 Dim NewSht As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arrFil, i As Long, boolFound As Boolean
 Dim targetPath As String

 foldNord = "C:\Users\Destination\nord\"
 targetPath = "C:\Users\Destination\nord\"
 fldSearch = "2020" 'the subfolder name to be searched for
 Set NewSht = Workbooks("Raw_data_2020.xlsm").Worksheets("files_list")
 lastRow = NewSht.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arrFil = NewSht.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).value 'put it in an array to run faster
 
 Set FSONord = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(foldNord)
 For Each FSOSubfld1 In FSONord.SubFolders
    For Each FSOSubfld2 In FSOSubfld1.SubFolders
        If FSOSubfld2.name = fldSearch Then
            For Each fsoFile In FSOSubfld2.Files
                If Right(fsoFile.name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                    boolFound = False
                    For i = 1 To UBound(arrFil)
                       If fsoFile.name = arrFil(i, 1) Then
                            boolFound = True: Exit For 'exiting to be faster
                       End If
                    Next i
                    If (Not boolFound) And (Not FSOLibrary.FileExists(targetPath & fsoFile.name)) Then
                        fsoFile.Copy targetPath
                    End If                    
                End If
            Next
            Exit for
        End If
    Next
 Next
End Sub
```

The last one is not tested (I did not have time to build a testing sheet)...

Please, test the code(s) I provided and send some feedback.

Comment: Something doesn't work. foldNord is rooth folder from which I want to copy or destination into which I want to paste copied files?

Comment: @Eve: Not sure i get you... So, `foldNord` should be the folder **where to paste the files from each 2020 subfolder**... Isn't it what you want?

Comment: foldNord = "U:\user\Documents\Nord" is folder where personal folders exist and inside personal folders there is folder 2020. targetpath  = "C:\Users\Destination\nord\" is where I want to save copied files

Comment: @Eve: Oh, I did not understood it in this way... I will immediately adapt the code.

Comment: @Eve: You did not answer my question regarding the need to also check against the A:A range in the sheet you used... I placed a piece of code also doing that (after editing), but it is not adapted from the above point of view. Should I adapt it, too? Adapted it, anyhow...

Comment: @Eve: Didn't you find some time to test the code(s) I posted? In the meantime I also tested the second variant, too. But, it should be good to send some feedback...

Comment: Sorry for delay. I have just tested second variant. I added targetpath as place to save copied files. It looks it works although its quite slow so it took its some time before it finsihed 200 files. I am not sure what makes it so slow, as coping from all subfolders was very fast. Thanks a lot for help

Comment: @Eve: Please, test the adapted code. The delay is not only a matter of number of files to be copied, it is also connected to the total number of subfolders to be iterated and check the files existence in the destination folder. The updated folder, exit the iteration between the subfolder subfolders, after working in a "2020" one... The array variant makes it anyhow faster than iteration between the sheet cells. I am curious how much time will you gain by this modification...

Comment: @Eve: Did you try the updated code? In order to be sure that you use the last variant, please refresh the page (this one) and only copy the code after that...

Comment: Something is not working. It copies only 2 files. Enters one personal folder>2020 copy one file, enters second personal folder>2020 copy one file and finishes. It looks like if finds in first folder file not in that list it takes it, but dosent continue to compare rest of the files

Comment: @Eve: Are you sure that you are using the last updated code? Did you refresh the page, as suggested? Does this code line `fsoFile.Copy targetPath: Exit For` exist in the code you use?

Comment: @Eve:  Now I placed another exiting line, for the case of finding 2020 folder, even if no file has been eligible for being copied. Try it please and send some feedback.

Comment: version with `fsoFile.Copy targetPath: Exit For` was coping only one file from each folder. This last version work well. Thanks

Comment: @Eve: Any gain in terms of speed?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub loopAllSubFolderSelectStartDirectory()
  Const RootFolder = "U:\user\Documents"
  Dim FSOLibrary As FileSystemObject
  Dim FSOFolder As Folder
  Dim folderName As String
  Dim Filename As String
  Dim SubFolder As Folder
  
  'Set the reference to the FSO Library
  Set FSOLibrary = New FileSystemObject
  Set FSOFolder = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(RootFolder)
  For Each SubFolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
    If SubFolder.Name Like "Nord*" Then
      LoopAllSubFolders SubFolder
    End If
  Next SubFolder
End Sub

Sub LoopAllSubFolders(FSOFolder As Folder)
  Const targetpath = "C:\Users\Destination\nord\"
  Const CopyFrom = "2020"
  Dim SubFolder As Folder
  Dim fsoFile As File
  Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
  Dim NewSht As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim Filename As String
  
  Dim found As Boolean
  
  Set Masterwb = Workbooks("Raw_data_2020.xlsm")
  Set NewSht = Masterwb.Worksheets("files_list")
  LastRow = NewSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  For Each SubFolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
    If SubFolder.Name = CopyFrom Then
      For Each fsoFile In FSOFolder.Files
        Filename = fsoFile.Name
        If Right(Filename, 4) = "xlsm" Then
          found = False
          For i = 1 To LastRow
            If Filename = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
              found = True
            End If
          Next i
          If Not found Then fsoFile.Copy targetpath
          Filename = Dir
        End If
      Next fsoFile
    End If
  Next SubFolder
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code but unfortunatelly it does not work.   "For Each SubFolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
    If SubFolder.Name = CopyFrom Then" here it si comparing name of personal folder with "2020" which is inside of personal folder, result will be always false